# Visual C++: ATL Implementation of an Interface

Tags: visual-c++, com, atl

I guess this is a real dumb question, but I couldn't find an answer. I'm trying to implement an COM interface using ATL. According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35tb9xw9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) I should use the **Implement Interface Wizard**. My question is how can I find the desired interface in this wizard. Do I have to go over all the libraries? Does is specified somewhere in the documentation of the interface ([IOleCommandTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683797%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To implement an interface you need:

- inherit your class from it
- add it onto interface map
- implement its methods

For example:

```
class CFoo : 
  // regular COM object base class, esp. those generated by ATL Simple Object Class Wizard
  public IOleCommandTarget
{

BEGIN_COM_MAP(CFoo)
  // ...
  COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IOleCommandTarget)
END_COM_MAP()

// ...

public:
// IOleCommandTarget
  STDMETHOD(Exec)(...) // IOleCommandTarget methods go here
  {
    // ...
  }
};
```

Comment: This is a very helpful answer. thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

To implement you need to do:

1. In the *h file let your CoClass inherit from interface.

2.In the *h file ,add an interface entry in the COM Map.

In the *h file ,add the prototype of interface methods.

In the *cpp file, implement the method of interface.